# Add mor info to flutter tabs

Tags: http, flutter, tabs

i would like to create dynamic tabs depending on categories from a HTTP service. creating the categories is not a problem as i could just use `List<Widget>.generate` however my problem is that depending on which tab is clicked i would like to retrieve the key of the clicked tab and make a HTTP call and thus populate the corresponding tab content, is there a way that i could associate more data with my tabs e.g include the key that i would use for a HTTP call? e.g

```
 List<Widget> _buildTabs() {
      return <Widget>[
        Tab(//insert key as a property),

      ];
    }
```

Comment: `TabBar` has `onTap` which will give you the index.

Comment: Yes i was thinking of getting the index and mapping it with a mapping list

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems: being notified of tab changes and building tabs based on data you receive from the network.

To be notified of tab switches, you have to use a `TabController` instead of `DefaultTabController`. The sample code [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html) should be quite useful. You will use its `.addListener()` method to be notified of tab changes.

Building the tabs dynamically is the other problem. You just receive your data and build your widgets, like any other Flutter app.